# MediaStreamAudioSourceNode memory leak

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api, web-frontend

`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` will not be garbage collected after `disconnect()` and dereference in function `demoMemoryLeak()`, which can cause a memory leak.

Reference:
source(MediaStreamAudioSourceNode) ---> at(MediaStreamTrack) ---> buffer1 (10M ArrayBuffer)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFuaD.png)

There is a correct way to release MediaStreamAudioSourceNode?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button onclick="demoNoMemoryLeak()"> no memory leak </button>
    <button onclick="demoMemoryLeak()"> memory leak using MediaStreamAudioSourceNode </button>
</div>
<script>
    async function demoNoMemoryLeak() {
        let ctx = new AudioContext();
        let buffer1 = new ArrayBuffer(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
        let at = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        at.onended = () => {
            console.log(buffer1);
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            at.stop();
            console.log('buffer1 is garbage collected');
        }, 5000);
    }

    async function demoMemoryLeak() {
        let ctx = new AudioContext();
        let buffer1 = new ArrayBuffer(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
        let at = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        at.onended = () => {
            console.log(buffer1);
        };
        let source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        source.connect(ctx.destination);
        setTimeout(() => {
            source.disconnect();
            source = null;
            at.stop();
            console.log('buffer1 is not garbage collected');
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your audioContext at the end of the disconnect, maybe that would help you out

```
ctx.close()
```